# How to get file content in queue job without file save any place Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel-5, queue, jobs

I'm using queue job with laravel 5.4. But I can't pass file content On job.

```
  //Controller

 public function trimVideoByFFmpeg()
  {
    try {

        $video = Input::file('video');//Video file
        $video_encode = base64_encode($video);//convert in base64_encode
        Log::info($video_encode);

        $job = new TrimJob($video_encode); //pass on job for trim
        $data = $this->dispatch($job);
        $result = $job->getResponse();
        $response = $result;
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        Log::error("checkFFmpeg : ", ['Exception' => $e->getMessage(), '\nTraceAsString' => $e->getTraceAsString()]);
        $response = "Something wrong";
    }
    return $response;
}



 //TrimJob.php
public function __construct($video,$name)
{
    Log::info('-------------------------------------------------------');
    Log::info('__construct()');
    $this->video = base64_decode($video,true);

    $cmd = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i $this->video 2>&1"; //Current Only get video info
    Log::info(['cmd'=>$cmd]);
    exec($cmd, $output, $result);

    log::info('__construct',[$output]);
}

public function handle()
{
    $video = $this->video;
    $output_file = Config::get('constant.OUTPUT_VIDEO_FFmpeg') . "test.mp4";;
    //$cmd = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i $video -ss 01.00 -t 02.00 -y $output_file 2>&1";
    $cmd = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i $video 2>&1";
    Log::info($cmd);
    exec($cmd, $output, $result);

    log::info('handle',[$output]);
}
```

This video file content successfully working in **__construc()** but is not working in **handle()**. How can I pass file data in queue?